# Column is blank but doesn't qualify where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I run this query:

```
 select LR.ID, LR.HIDE 
 from Location_Room LR 
 where LR.LID = 19624
```

I get:

[image]

When I run this 2nd query:

```
 select LR.HIDE, ID 
 from Location_Room LR 
 where LR.LID = 19624 
   AND (LR.HIDE = ' ' OR LR.HIDE IS NULL or LR.HIDE = '' or datalength(LR.HIDE) = 0)
```

I get this result:

[image]

I need to check that `HIDE` isn't null or blank, but can't seem to do so.

The column is set up like this:

[image]

Why is this happening? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Try to check the result of the query: select distinct LR.HIDE from Location_Room LR where LR.LID=19624

Comment: Looks like the column is not blank, try select the hex value of `HIDE` to see if there are any not printable character.

Comment: It is worth noting that you are begging for trouble if you start using NULL and ' ' interchangeably. There are arguments for using a blank character [source](http://vampirebasic.blogspot.com/2009/01/sql-server-null-varchar-vs-empty.html) but your design should utilize one or the other consistently, at least in distinct columns.

Comment: @jannagy02 - this returns same blank value as in the 1st screenshot

Comment: @Jens - I ran this SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), LR.HIDE), 1) from Location_Room LR where LR.LID=19624  to pull out the hex value and I get 0x00

Comment: @iKode So that means that you have only 1 value which is not '' or ' ' or NULL. Try to get the code of the character like this: select distinct ASCII(LR.HIDE) from Location_Room LR where LR.LID=19624

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have a funny character in the data.  You can see the ASCII value of the first character in `hide` by using `ASCII()`:

```
select ascii(left(hide, 1))
from Location_Room;
```

Or perhaps:

```
select ascii(left(ltrim(rtrim(hide)), 1))
from Location_Room;
```

Comment: both of these return 0

Comment: @iKode . . . `\000` is, indeed, a funky character.  You can do `replace(hide, char(0), '')` to get rid of it.